# add new disk in /etc/tgt/targets.conf and reload without affect other disks/initiator hosts

Tags: linux, rhel, scsi, iscsi

I have added a new disk to the server:

```
[root@ns1 tgt]# lsblk |grep sdh
sdh           8:112  0  600M  0 disk
```

Also, I have created a new entry for `/dev/sdh` in `/etc/tgt/targets.conf`

```
[root@ns1 tgt]# cat /etc/tgt/targets.conf |grep /dev/
                                         direct-store /dev/sdb
                                         direct-store /dev/sdc
                                         direct-store /dev/sdd
                                         direct-store /dev/sde
                                         direct-store /dev/sdf
                                         direct-store /dev/sdg
                                         direct-store /dev/sdh
[root@ns1 tgt]#
```

How can I reload the new configuration and make available the new lun? I have tried `systemctl reload tgtd`, `tgt-admin -e` and `tgt-admin --ready ALL`, but none has worked. Bellow we can see there is no `/dev/sdh` yet.

```
[root@ns1 tgt]# tgtadm --mode target --op show|grep /dev/
            Backing store path: /dev/sdb
            Backing store path: /dev/sdc
            Backing store path: /dev/sdd
            Backing store path: /dev/sde
            Backing store path: /dev/sdf
            Backing store path: /dev/sdg
[root@ns1 tgt]#
```

I have tested with `systemctl restart tgtd` and it has worked, but it affect the initiator hosts. ie after restart `tgtd` (log from some initiator host):

```
Jun  6 18:20:41 rac1 kernel: connection1:0: detected conn error (1020)
Jun  6 18:20:41 rac1 iscsid: iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1020 - ISCSI_ERR_TCP_CONN_CLOSE: TCP connection closed) state (3)
Jun  6 18:20:43 rac1 iscsid: iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1020 - ISCSI_ERR_TCP_CONN_CLOSE: TCP connection closed) state (2)
Jun  6 18:20:43 rac1 kernel: connection1:0: detected conn error (1020)
Jun  6 18:20:45 rac1 kernel: connection1:0: detected conn error (1020)
Jun  6 18:20:45 rac1 iscsid: iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1020 - ISCSI_ERR_TCP_CONN_CLOSE: TCP connection closed) state (2)
Jun  6 18:20:46 rac1 kernel: session1: session recovery timed out after 5 secs
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 multipathd: checker failed path 8:112 in map data1
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 multipathd: data1: remaining active paths: 0
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 kernel: device-mapper: multipath: Failing path 8:112.
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 kernel: device-mapper: multipath: Failing path 8:80.
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 kernel: device-mapper: multipath: Failing path 8:96.
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 multipathd: checker failed path 8:80 in map fra2
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 multipathd: fra2: remaining active paths: 0
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 multipathd: checker failed path 8:96 in map fra3
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 multipathd: fra3: remaining active paths: 0
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 iscsid: iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1020 - ISCSI_ERR_TCP_CONN_CLOSE: TCP connection closed) state (2)
Jun  6 18:20:47 rac1 kernel: connection1:0: detected conn error (1020)
Jun  6 18:20:49 rac1 iscsid: iscsid: connection1:0 is operational after recovery (4 attempts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the config file? e.g.

```
tgt-admin --update ALL -c /etc/tgt/targets.conf
```

I also noticed in my server logs (49 targets) that systemd was timing out on start, leaving the state inconsistent.  Creating `/etc/systemd/system/tgt.service.d/extend-timeout.conf` thusly allowed clean startup:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=5m
```

aside: `bs-type aio` for the LUNs also helped with startup time.